# Raspberry Pi board is not detecting LAN connection

Tags: networking, ethernet, ubuntu

I'm working on Raspberry Pi board with Ubuntu OS but it's not detecting the LAN connection and I am not getting an IP address when I type `ifconfig`.

I've added below code to `/etc/netplan/01-config.yaml`:

```
version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: yes
      addresses: [192.168.0.1/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
```

And executed the command `dhclient etho` but still I am not able to get an IP address, how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

assuming eth0 is the name of your network interface and 192.168.0.1 is the ip of your gateway,

if you want your pi on dhcp, try this config:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: yes
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
```

if you want a static ip: (lets say 192.168.0.15)

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.15/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
```

after saving, run

```
sudo netplan apply
```

Comment: You should mention in your answer (please don't use a comment) where to do these entries.